# Grizzly web server with domain

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I have a subdomain. I want attach it to Java JAX-RS project with grizzly server implementation.
When i set up on localhost:8080 it works well, but i can't figure out, how can i set up it with my subdomain or domain.

Thanks

Comment: Configure a DNS A record for the subdomain to point to the IP of your host.

Comment: Thanks, I have configured DNS record for subdomain and then i changed the BASE_URL for grizzly to just created subdomain. Is there anything else need to do?

Comment: Yes, i checked the subdomain, it's working, so DNS records are correct.
When i change the BASE_URL to my subdomain (f.e xx.subdomain.com) i got java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Comment: hmm.. i have a CNAME record for that subdomain actually instead of A record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** You need a static IP address.

You should not set the grizzly BASE_URL to the subdomain and you should not use a `CNAME` record. You should set the BASE_URL to a static IP address, and point the subdomain to that IP using an `A` record.

Example: you own `domain.com` and want to attach `sub.domain.com` to your application.

1. Get a static IP address (e.g. `50.12.xxx.yy`)
2. Add an `A (Host)` record: `sub` --> `50.12.xxx.yy`
3. Set the Grizzly BASE_URL: `50.12.xxx.yy`
4. Go to http://sub.domain.com and you will hit your app

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I got it trough by myself at the end, and made a decision to use glassfish as application server instead.